# Gitlab Artifcacts Store Previous Artifacts

Tags: gitlab, devops, cicd, artifact, gitlab-pipelines

Using Gitlab Job Artifacts: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

How do I store the previous run's artifacts along with the current run?

I know I can use the name keyword in order to give my artifacts a unique name. This will allow me to store the unique artifacts of every single pipeline I ever ran.

But I'd like to only store say the last 3 builds. How can I ensure that the 3rd build replaces the current build?

Answer (score 0):

First, use special folder for your artifact and give them a unique name (for example you can add a commit or build number to the name)